# htaccess - Some of my 301 redirects are working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Working on a website upgrade and upgrading a bunch of pages. I have these three `RewriteRule`'s and one of them is not working. I'm novice to `htaccess` so I'm assuming I'm using the wrong syntax.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)Accessibility/$ /$1accessibility/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Accessibility/Multi-Year-Plan/$ /$1accessibility/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Accessibility/Standard-Policy/$ /$1accessibility/standard-policy/ [R=301,L]
```

In the same order, this is what is working in my dev environment.

1. Works
2. Doesn't work
3. Works

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine rule 1 and rule 2 into one then test:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)Accessibility(/Multi-Year-Plan)?/?$ /$1accessibility/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Accessibility/Standard-Policy/$ /$1accessibility/standard-policy/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's not working, I'm getting redirected to `/$accessibility/` when I try `/Accessibility`. However the `/Multi-Year-Plan/` is working now.

Comment: Test it in a new browser as using these rules I am getting redirected from `localhost/Accessibility/` to `localhost/accessibility/`. Also make sure these rules are first rules in your root .htaccess

Comment: It worked in incognito mode. I thought using a new tab was enough, clearly not. Thanks. What if I needed to append more urls, would it be something such as: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)Accessibility(/Multi-Year-Plan)?(/Policy)?/?$`

Comment: If you're trying to redirect `/Accessibility/Policy` to `/accessibility/` then use: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)Accessibility(/Multi-Year-Plan|Policy)?/?$ /$1accessibility/ [R=301,L]`